# Do I need to use Reachability for sending in-app Email?

Tags: iphone, email, networking, reachability

According to Apple; 
"missing network alerts is the third most common reason for applications being returned to developers for modification."

So when exactly is this required? i.e. do some functions have this catered for?

I simply need to send an in-app email (code working), so it seems rather laborious to now have to figure out how to implement all that Reachability code as well.

Comment: There may be times when n/w is not reachable, so your application will crash, so it is always a good programming practice to take care of exceptions. Apple has already provided the Reachability code, so it is just copy and paste and use it in your application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Reachability is generally a good practice... To prevent user actions that will not succeed. (Like writing a long text to finally get an error message, losing your work)

...But in your case, for in-app email, **you do not need** to check network availability.

Because the mail will be handled by Mail app, which already does this ***very well***, by keeping mail in outbox, mail that will be sent later, when network available...

Answer (score 0):

The network reachability class is available in Apple documentation, you only have to download it and use it in your code. You can have it from this [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Listings/Classes_Reachability_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007324-Classes_Reachability_m-DontLinkElementID_6).